# How to do a Parse query for the objectId of a pointer

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

In my Installations class in Parse, I have a column called "currentLogin", which contains a pointer to a user. I can query the Installation class for the user using the line:

```
[userQuery whereKey:@"currentLogin" equalTo:user];
```

But I would like to be able to query the Installation class using the objectId of the user. I.e., to find users in the `currentLogin` column whose `objectId`s match the one I am querying for. How would I do this?

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly, at least in the iOS SDK. You need to create a placeholder object to use in the query, which is potentially problematic for users depending on your security settings.

In either case you could do it with the RESTful interface, because then you construct the query yourself and the pointer is really just a little wrapper containing the object ID. Or, you can pass the object ID to cloud code and have it to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a user with just an object id like this

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser objectWithoutDataWithObjectId:@"USER_OBJECT_ID"];
```

Now you can use the user in any query.